# Como usar as variáveis do Windows no Delphi?

Tags: delphi, variáveis, delphi-xe4, object-pascal

Olá, estou criando um projeto no `Delphi`, porém, ele precisa criar alguns arquivos, não daria uma boa impressão se ele fizesse isto no local onde ele está, então eu preciso que estes arquivos sejam criados na pasta temporária do Windows para evitar eventuais problemas. Dez de já agradeço por ter lido minha pergunta.

Comment: Variáveis de ambiente do windows?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Para obter informações sobre o ambiente, use a [função `GetEnvironmentVariable`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/pt-br/library/windows/desktop/ms683188%28v=vs.85%29.aspx), segundo [essa página](http://www.swissdelphicenter.ch/torry/showcode.php?id=2277), você pode usá-la do seguinte modo:

```
function GetEnvVarValue(const VarName: string): string;
var
  BufSize: Integer;  
begin
  BufSize := GetEnvironmentVariable(PChar(VarName), nil, 0);
  if BufSize > 0 then
  begin
    SetLength(Result, BufSize - 1);
    GetEnvironmentVariable(PChar(VarName),
      PChar(Result), BufSize);
  end
  else
    Result := '';
end;
```

Exemplo de utilização:

```
ShowMessage(GetEnvVarValue('windir')); // Exibe a localização do diretório do Windows
```

Os valores que você pode passar como argumento para a função acima são:

- `ALLUSERSPROFILE`
- `APPDATA`
- `CLIENTNAME`
- `CommonProgramFiles`
- `COMPUTERNAME`
- `ComSpec`
- `HOMEDRIVE`
- `HOMEPATH`
- `LOGONSERVER`
- `NUMBER_OF_PROCESSORS`
- `OS`
- `Path`
- `PATHEXT`
- `PCToolsDir`
- `PROCESSOR_ARCHITECTURE`
- `PROCESSOR_IDENTIFIER`
- `PROCESSOR_LEVEL`
- `PROCESSOR_REVISION`
- `ProgramFiles`
- `SESSIONNAME`
- `SystemDrive`
- `SystemRoot`
- `TEMP`
- `TMP`
- `USERDOMAIN`
- `USERNAME`
- `USERPROFILE`
- `windir`

Uma lista de variáveis e seus valores padrões podem ser vistos nessa [página da Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Environment_variable#Default_values).

Comment: Obrigado amigo!

Comment: Farei isto assim que o site liberar, e novamente obrigado!

Answer (score -1):

Para que funcione, agreguen "windows" a USES
Quedaria asi:

uses
System.SysUtils, System.Types, System.UITypes, System.Classes, System.Variants,
windows;

yo estaba usando firemonkey o FMX, y me faltaba agregar ese 'windows' , y me pase horas averiguar de ello, agregando funcionó